# React Navigation - How to access this.props.navigation in axios instance

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, react-navigation

I have an axios instance to set my `baseURL` and set the `interceptors` but everytime i want to use `this.props.navigation` i got an error `undefined is not an object (this.props.navigation)`

here's the code:

```
// Axios Setting
api.axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response)=>{
  return response
}, (error) => {
  if(error.response == undefined){
    return Promise.reject(
    Alert.alert("Perhatian","Tidak dapat terhubung ke server \n\n Cek koneksi internet anda",[
      {text:"OK", onPress:()=>BackHandler.exitApp()}
    ])
    )
  } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
    return Promise.reject(
      goToLogin("Login", null)
    );
  }
})

//goToLogin Function on different js :
export function goToLogin(routeName, params){
  return(
    Alert.alert("Peringatan", "Sepertinya akun ini sudah login di perangkat lain\n\nsilahkan logout dan login kembali untuk dapat mengakses kembali",[
      {text:'Logout', onPress:()=>{
        console.log(this.props) // i got undefined on this line
        // this.props.navigation.dispatch(
        //   NavigationActions.navigate({
        //     routeName:routeName,
        //     key:routeName,
        //     params:params
        //   })
        // ),
        // deleteAllUser()
      }}
    ],{cancelable: false})
  )
}
```

How can i access `this.props.navigation` when the component (axios) is not on screen?

Comment: Maybe this guide in the documentation will help you figure out what to do: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: You need to pass the navigation object from your component  to  API module and while calling goToLogin you sholud pass it as a parameter , so that navigation object will be available inside goToLogin function.

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq if i do that, i could add `goToLogin()` in all my API instead of create one code to all connection

Comment: @needsleep the docs is not what i need, [this docs](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop.html) almost help me, but I need to pass the `function` instead of `React.Component`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get.

Comment: @flix My thinking was that if you set up the NavigationService as described in the docs correctly, you can then import the NavigationService into your interceptor file and navigate to the login screen like so: NavigationService.navigate('LoginScreen'); You don't need a component with this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use the navigation prop from functions that are not React Components and probably don't have access to the navigation at all. In these cases, it's recommended to use a Navigation Service as described in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

Here is a simple example of how you can use it with axios interceptors to have a better understanding of what I'm suggesting:

https://snack.expo.io/BkLWor8FX

On App.js I make a GET call using axios to a non existent url like "https://www.google.coms". The interceptor will handle the failed request (Interceptors.js) and it will use the NavigationService(NavigationService.js) to redirect to the error screen.

I think you can use something similar in your case. Good luck!

Comment: the code looks promising, i will tried it, thanks for the code

Comment: I tried this way but i keep getting undefined for the `navigator` in the `NavigationService`, here is my question, please please help me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577861/react-navigation-navigate-without-navigation-props-example-not-working