# React navigation navigate without navigation props example not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a react-native app and I'm using the new Context API to manage the storage and stuff, now I'm wrapping the `createAppContainer(AuthNavigator)` in the `<Provider>` created by the context api, so in order to navigate from the Context API file, I tried to do the exact same example I found in the documentation by creating the `NavigationService` and passing the `ref` of the `AppContainer` to the `NavigationService` and using `{ NavigationActions }`, somehow it's not working neither it's throwing any kind of error

here is my router.js

```
  const AuthNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Authenticated: Authenticated,
      UnAuthenticated: UnAuthenticated,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: props.is_authenticated ? 'Authenticated' : 'UnAuthenticated'
    }
  )

  const Router = createAppContainer(AuthNavigator);

  return (

    <Provider style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
      <Router ref={ ref => NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(ref) } />
      <DropdownAlert
        successColor="#26296A"
        titleStyle={{ fontFamily: 'DINNextLTArabic-Regular', lineHeight: 18, color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}
        messageStyle={{ fontFamily: 'DINNextLTArabic-Regular', lineHeight: 16, color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}
        imageStyle={{ display: 'none' }}
        ref={ (ref) => Flash.setDropDown(ref) }
      />
    </Provider>

  )

}

export default ReactNavigator;
```

here is my navigation-service file

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(nav_ref) { navigator = nav_ref }

function navigate(route_name, params) {
  navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      route_name,
      params
    })
  )
}

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator
};
```

and here is the Provider from which i want to navigate

it's a React Context API

```
import NavigationService from '@utils/navigation-service';

onReceived(notification) {

  console.warn(notification.payload.additionalData);

  console.warn('triggered');

  NavigationService.navigate('Chat');

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you have set up everything as you should. My only guess is that the "onReceived" function is called before the "setTopLevelNavigator". Try to add some console.logs in the above functions to see if this is the case. Cause if the onReceived is called first, then the navigator reference is not set yet so the call to change screens would fail.

Comment: Nice one actually i'll try it later .. and respond

Answer (score 0):

Your `route_name` should be `routeName` instead according to the example on react-navigation website (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

They require the keys `routeName` & `params` specifically to work